# IOConsole Updater Assertion Error after inserting data to MYSQL using HIBERNATE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, console, assertion

I am getting an IOConsole Updater assetion failed error on eclipse after inserting data to mysql using hibernate and this situation causes that the program jumps over some codes and continue working in a bad way.
When I cancel the insertion method that saves value to database , everything works right.

[here you can see the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkofi.png)

**j2n-hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <!-- SQL Dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorialdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <!-- it was false , i make true -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    
    <!-- Specifying Session Context -->
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    
    <!-- Mapping With Model Class Containing Annotations -->
    <mapping class="com.binance.api.examples.TradeStats" />
    
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateUtil.java :**

```
package com.binance.api.examples;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

static {
    try{
        loadSessionFactory();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Exception while initializing hibernate util.. ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void loadSessionFactory(){

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("/j2n-hibernate.cfg.xml");
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(TradeStats.class);
    ServiceRegistry srvcReg = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(srvcReg);
}

public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {

    Session retSession=null;
        try {
            retSession=sessionFactory.openSession();
        }catch(Throwable t){
        System.err.println("Exception while getting session.. ");
        t.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(retSession == null) {
            System.err.println("session is discovered null");
        }

        return retSession;
}
}
```

**TradeStats.java**

```
package com.binance.api.examples;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tradestats")
public class TradeStats implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="TRADE_ID")
private Long tradeId;

@Column(name="COIN_NAME")
private String coinName;

@Column(name="COIN_BOUGHT_LAST_PRICE")
private double coinBoughtLastPrice;

@Column(name="COIN_SOLD_LAST_PRICE")
private double coinSoldLastPrice;

@Column(name="STOP_VALUE")
private double stopValue;

@Column(name="PROFIT_VALUE")
private double profitValue;

@Column(name="GAIN")
private double gain;

@Column(name="LOSS")
private double loss;

@Column(name="PREDICTION_PRICE")
private double predictionPrice;

@Column(name="PRICE_AVERAGE")
private double priceAverage;

@Column(name="TOTAL_GAIN")
private double totalGain;

@Column(name="TOTAL_LOSS")
private double totalLoss;

@Column(name="DURATION")
private int duration;

public Long getTradeId() {
    return tradeId;
}

public void setTradeId(Long tradeId) {
    this.tradeId = tradeId;
}

public String getCoinName() {
    return coinName;
}

public void setCoinName(String coinName) {
    this.coinName = coinName;
}

public double getCoinBoughtLastPrice() {
    return coinBoughtLastPrice;
}

public void setCoinBoughtLastPrice(double coinBoughtLastPrice) {
    this.coinBoughtLastPrice = coinBoughtLastPrice;
}

public double getCoinSoldLastPrice() {
    return coinSoldLastPrice;
}

public void setCoinSoldLastPrice(double coinSoldLastPrice) {
    this.coinSoldLastPrice = coinSoldLastPrice;
}

public double getStopValue() {
    return stopValue;
}

public void setStopValue(double stopValue) {
    this.stopValue = stopValue;
}

public double getProfitValue() {
    return profitValue;
}

public void setProfitValue(double profitValue) {
    this.profitValue = profitValue;
}

public double getGain() {
    return gain;
}

public void setGain(double gain) {
    this.gain = gain;
}

public double getLoss() {
    return loss;
}

public void setLoss(double loss) {
    this.loss = loss;
}

public double getPredictionPrice() {
    return predictionPrice;
}

public void setPredictionPrice(double predictionPrice) {
    this.predictionPrice = predictionPrice;
}

public double getPriceAverage() {
    return priceAverage;
}

public void setPriceAverage(double priceAverage) {
    this.priceAverage = priceAverage;
}

public double getTotalGain() {
    return totalGain;
}

public void setTotalGain(double totalGain) {
    this.totalGain = totalGain;
}

public double getTotalLoss() {
    return totalLoss;
}

public void setTotalLoss(double totalLoss) {
    this.totalLoss = totalLoss;
}

public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TradeStats [tradeId=" + tradeId + ", coinName=" + coinName + ", coinBoughtLastPrice="
            + coinBoughtLastPrice + ", coinSoldLastPrice=" + coinSoldLastPrice + ", stopValue=" + stopValue
            + ", profitValue=" + profitValue + ", gain=" + gain + ", loss=" + loss + ", predictionPrice="
            + predictionPrice + ", priceAverage=" + priceAverage + ", totalGain=" + totalGain + ", totalLoss="
            + totalLoss + ", duration=" + duration + "]";
}


}
```

**TradeStatsDao.java :**

```
package com.binance.api.examples;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TradeStatsDao {

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<TradeStats> getTradeStatsList(){
 
        Session session = null;
        List<TradeStats> tradeList = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            String queryStr = "Select trade from TradeStats";
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
            tradeList = query.list();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // handle exception here
        } finally {
            try {if(session != null) session.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
        return tradeList;
    }
 
 public TradeStats getTradeStatsById(Long tradeId){
     
        Session session = null;
        TradeStats trd = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            trd = session.get(TradeStats.class,tradeId);
 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // handle exception here
        } finally {
            try {if(session != null) session.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
        return trd;
    }
 
 public void insertTradeStats(TradeStats trd) {
     
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(trd);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("inserted tradestats : "+trd.getCoinName());
            transaction.commit();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // handle exception here
            if(transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            try {if(session != null) session.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
 
 public void deleteTradeStats(TradeStats trd) {
     
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(trd);
            transaction.commit();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("deleted employee: "+trd.getCoinName());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // handle exception here
            if(transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            try {if(session != null) session.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }
 

}
```